# How to get the data from pandas series when the indices are integers?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I am trying to understand Series. I have created a series as following

```
p=pd.Series(data=['a','b','c','d'],index=[4,3,2,1])
```

when I used p[[1,2]] python returned

```
1    d
2    c
dtype: object
```

I am expecting a result

```
4    a
3    b
dtype: object
```

How do I get this expected result? I would like to know how python differentiates between indices and the index values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series are output is based on index. If you want to get first 2 elements use iloc:

```
import pandas as pd

data =pd.Series(data=['a','b','c','d'],index=[4,3,2,1])
print(data.iloc[:2])
```

Output:

```
4    a
3    b
dtype: object
```